# Difference Between uses-permission-sdk-23 and uses-permission?

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest

I just come to know newer tag in android manifest file called "**uses-permission-sdk-23**"

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Can anybody please provide difference between this two?

Comment: I wonder what's so special about SDK 23.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**if the app is running on a device with SDK version 23 or higher. If the device is running SDK version 22 or lower**

when you update an app to include a new feature that requires an additional permission. If a user updates an app on a device that is running SDK version 22 or lower, the system prompts the user at install time to grant all new permissions that are declared in that update. If a new feature is minor enough, you may prefer to disable the feature altogether on those devices, so the user does not have to grant additional permissions to update the app. By using the **uses-permission-sdk-23** element instead of **uses-permission**

**you can request the permission only if the app is running on platforms that support the runtime permissions model, in which the user grants permissions to the app while it is running.**

for More info refer this.[uses - Permission sdk 23](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-sdk-23-element.html)

Comment: Great answer , but i did't understood one thing , should i use both if them if i would like to support older version or uses-permission-sdk-23 is enouge ?

Comment: @JesusDimrix no you cant use just  <uses-permission-sdk-23> this permission work only for that device who have runtime permission support. so you should use <uses- permission> also or you can only use <uses -permission>  that support >23 device just you have code for  request runtime permission.

Answer (score 8):

## Summary

`<uses-permission>` applies to all SDKs and `<uses-permission-sdk-23>` will apply the permission only to SDK 23+.

## When should you use `<uses-permission-sdk-23>`?

- For Android SDK 23 and above, you *have the option* to request the permission at runtime but the permissions will be in their default state upon installation and the user will not be prompted at installation. (Essentially this can be used to prompt the user to grant the permission on a need-to-use basis and you have the opportunity to provide an explanation of why it's needed.)
- However, for SDK 22 and below, the user is prompted at installation for permissions. As some permissions can seem suspicious or dodgy to the user, you may not want to request these for SDK 22 and below as you can't provide an explaination of why you need them beforehand, hence the `<uses-permission-sdk-23>` tag.
- *Additionally:* the documentation is unclear as to whether `sdk-23` permissions also cause the app to be filtered in the Play Store, but if it was your intention to do this, the documentation recommends that you make use of `<uses-feature>` elements instead to declare hardware compatability.

## Recommendation

Generally, it is considered best practice to use `<uses-permission-sdk-23>` if your app does not need to support SDK 22 and below, or if the permission you are requesting is not needed for SDK 22 or below as it is then clear that this permission is requested at runtime.

Otherwise, `<uses-permission>` should be used as this is backwards compatible and the behavior will be correct on any SDK version; 22 and below, permissions will be requested at installation. 23 and above, it's up to you to request at runtime.

> You should request permissions at runtime wherever possible as it allows you to explain to your user why you need certain permissions rather than just prompting them with a list of permissions at install time when the user has likely not established trust in the app.

## Notes

Both of these accept a `maxSdkVersion` attribute that can be used when a permission was required for older devices but is not required for newer devices. (For example, the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` example shown in the Android documentation.)

Reference: [(Android Documentation)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro#perms)

Comment: Please explain, I can use the option to request the permission at runtime without the sdk-23 tag , by calling the function : "requestPermissions(context...." this function was added in SDK 24.1 I don't understand .

Comment: @StavBodik If I understand correctly, by adding permissions with the `sdk-23` tag, whilst they won't work on SDK 22-, these permissions will not be listed when the app is installed, instead you request them at will in the app at any time. I seem to have mixed them up in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

By using the `<uses-permission-sdk-23>` element instead of `<uses-permission>`, you can request the permission only if the app is running on platforms that support the runtime permissions model, in which the user grants permissions to the app while it is running.

This has been introduced **to support runtime permission feature of Marshmallow** (API-23) onwards.

This simply specifies that an app wants a particular permission, but only if the app is running on a device with SDK version 23 or higher. If the device is running SDK version 22 or lower, the app does not have the specified permission.
This element is useful when you update an app to include a new feature that requires an additional permission. If a user updates an app on a device that is running SDK version 22 or lower, the system prompts the user at install time to grant all new permissions that are declared in that update.

You can reffer to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-sdk-23-element.html).

Answer (score 1):

user-permission-sdk-23 specifies that the app that wants a particular permission is running on SDK version 23 or higher.
It is used when you update your app to run SDK 23 elements and the users running a lower API which does not support the new elements.

[Android manifest - user permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-sdk-23-element.html)

Answer (score 1):

Specifies that an app wants a particular permission, but only if the app is running on a device with API level 23 or higher. If the device is running API level 22 or lower, the app does not have the specified permission.

Answer (score -1):

see the documentation 
[uses permission](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-sdk-23-element.html)

Use

```
<uses-permission-sdk23>
```

to apply permission for Marshmallow devices only.