# Camera permission is not working on Marshmallow and above devices and crashes

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-7.1-nougat

Since I have made a flashlight application and it works properly on the device which have `SDK 22` and below. But when I come to check on marshmallow and above devices, it doesn't run and crashes at the beginning only I asked for permission using following code but it doesn't seems to be working at all. here is my code for requesting permission of camera at run time. here is my code:

```
if( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    5);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[]  permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 5) {
            if  (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Now user should be able to use camera
            }
            else {
                // Your app will not have this permission. Turn off all functions
                // if permission not granted it will force close the app

            }
        }
```

I have tried in marshmallow, nougat devices but it doesnt ask for camera permission and i have to go through manually from `setting-app-flashlight-permission-allow`. can anyone help me please. Currently I am testing my app in `Lineage os 7.1.1`

Comment: try uninstall->install and see if its asking for permission. It might happen that you clicked that `never ask again` checkbox by mistake

Comment: Nope it doesn't ask for permission at all, it simply crashes. but the app works fine if I  allow permission manually as i said above from setting-app-permission-allow.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the SDK 23 permission in manifest. add the below line in manifest then you will get runtime permission callback.

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570533/difference-between-uses-permission-sdk-23-and-uses-permission/35570651)

Answer (score 1):

Just you change only if condition your code is perfect like this,

```
if( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                5);


    }

}
```

to

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
     if( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
             android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                5);


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code and call the "requestPermission" method in onCreate of the Activity:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 2;
    List<String> mPermission=new ArrayList<String>();

public void requestPermission()
            {
                try {

                    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                            != MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        mPermission.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

                    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            != MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED


                            )
                        mPermission.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

                        );

                    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            != MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        mPermission.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);




                    if(mPermission.size()>0)

                    {
                        String[] array = mPermission.toArray(new String[mPermission.size()]);
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, array, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);

                        // If any permission aboe not allowed by user, this condition will execute every tim, else your else part will work
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Overwrite the method "onRequestPermissionsResult":

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    Log.e("Req Code", "" + requestCode);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults.length == mPermission.size())             {
            for(int i=0;i<grantResults.length;i++)
            {
                if(grantResults[i] == MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
               //don't do anything....
                }
                else{
                    mPermission=new ArrayList<String>();
                    requestPermission();
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"permition not granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mPermission=new ArrayList<String>();
            requestPermission();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sir your code is asking for multiple permission camera and storage and in my case I need only camera permission.

Comment: You can use only camera permission remove extra code. I added because If you use camera then you will need to save the captured image and for that you will need other permissions too.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(currentAPIVersion>= 23)
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    alertBuilder.setTitle("Camera Permission Necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setMessage("Camera permission is necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                    alert.show();

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

do this way:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(UserProfileActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UserProfileActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    5);

        } else {
           //start flashlight

        }




@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {

            case 5: {
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                    if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        //start flashlight
                        Log.d("Permissions CAMERA", "Permission Granted: " + permissions[i]);


                    } else if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                        Log.d("Permissions CAMERA", "Permission Denied: " + permissions[i]);


                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            default: {
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            } break;
        }
}
```

Comment: The above code shows several issue like: can't resolve symbol UserProfileActivity, can't resolve symbol do & can't resolve symbol work. however @override doesn't have any issue.

Comment: UserProfileActivity is your activity name. and  DO CAMERA WORK means put your camera capture logic there. that time you have camera permission so that you can do camera work without any issue

Comment: Okay but how do I remove does red marks which says can't resolve symbol UserProfileActivity, Do & Work?

Comment: for UserProfileActivity, you can put this or YOURCLASSNAME.this.  for do & work use camera to capture image

Comment: in your case, at DO CAMERA WORK start flashlight function. and at Log.d("Permissions CAMERA", "Permission Granted: " + permissions[i]); also start flashlight function

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem but managed to fixed it. Here's my case (I don't know if its the same as yours but it's worth a try)

So I have this two activities namely: `MainActivity`, and `FlashlightActivity`.

I used to ask for camera permission explicitly in `FlaslightActivity` just before I tap the switch button but I forgot that I was checking if a user's phone has a camera in the `onCreate()` method. while I was asking for permission `onClick` of the switch button of the flashlight, in which that was after I checked if a user's phone has a camera. So what I did was to ask for the permission in my `MainActivity` just before I start `FlashlightActivity`.

```
flashBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(hasPermission()){
                Intent flashIntent = new Intent("FlashlightActivity");
                startActivity(flashIntent);
            }else{
                requestPermission();
            }
        }
    });
```

So basically ask for the permission before you call any Camera related stuffs